# Intersection of Two lists with index using lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary that contains the index and matched elements of two sequences.
for example:-

```
List<string> A = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
List<string> B = new List<string> { "a", "d", "e", "f" };
```

Now I want to build a dictionary that looks like this.

```
// Expected Output:-
// { "a" , 0 }
// { "d" , 3 }
// { "e" , 4 }
// { "f" , 5 }
```

where the first entry in dictionary is the common element in both the lists and second one is the index of that in the first list(A).
Not sure on how to phrase a Lambda Expression to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Do to so, for each element in `B` use `IndexOf` in the `A` collection. Then use `ToDictionary` to convert it to the dictionary form you wanted

```
List<string> A = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
List<string> B = new List<string> { "a", "d", "e", "f" };

 var result = B.Select(item => new { item, Position = A.IndexOf(item) })
               .ToDictionary(key => key.item, value => value.Position);
```

Keep in mind that the items in `B` must be unique for it to not fail on `KeyAlreadyExists`. In that case:

```
 var result = B.Distinct()
               .Select(item => new { item, Position = A.IndexOf(item) })
               .ToDictionary(key => key.item, value => value.Position);
```

If you do not want results for items that weren't found:

```
 var result = B.Distinct()
               .Select(item => new { item, Position = A.IndexOf(item) })
               .Where(item => item.Position != -1
               .ToDictionary(key => key.item, value => value.Position);
```

Comment: Note that using `Distinct` may cause the alteration of the index. Although unless OP wants to use `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`, he has to do that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I'm doing the distinct on the second list whereas the indexOf is on the first list - so it won't change the indexes

Comment: The OP has asked for the intersection of the two lists. As I read the question it is not guaranteed that all the elements in `B` are also present in `A` (as in the example). To address this you'd have to filter all elements with an index `< 0`.

Comment: @fknx - I know and you are right but the OP also didn't address to the cases where List A has more than 1 instance of a value and what to do - so I kept it as close to what he explicitly said and gave for input/output :)

Comment: @GiladGreen Okay, I guess its a fair assumption to make :)

Comment: @Programmerzzz - Did this help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
List<string> A = new List<string>{"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"};
List<string> B = new List<string>{"a","d","e","f"};
var result = B.ToDictionary(k => k, v => A.IndexOf(b)});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
List<string> A = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
List<string> B = new List<string> { "a", "d", "e", "f" };

Dictionary<string, int> result = B.ToDictionary(x => x, x => A.IndexOf(x));
```